# Android - Custom View and ImageView on XML but Custom View not visible

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, ondraw

I try to use setContentView (R.layout.main) to display both an imageview and a Custom View. Somehow only the imageview can be shown but the Custom view is not visible (i.e. Bitmap ButtonStart not visible). I tested my code for onDraw and Texture class (responsible to load a bitmap object) somewhere else and it works fine. So I dunno what goes wrong...

Code for Custom view

```
public class TitleView extends View {

private Bitmap ButtonStart;

public TitleView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super (context, attrs);
    Texture t2 = new Texture(context);
    t2.loadFromAsset("button_Start.png");
    ButtonStart = t2.getBitmap();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap (ButtonStart, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_image);
}
}
```

main_screen_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainScreenLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/mainScreenImage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/screenimage"
>
</ImageView>
<com.lowbband.chimera.TitleView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/titleview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

With the code above, only screenimage was shown...

Comment: I'd say that because your ImageView's height is set to fill parent, there is no space left for your TitleView.

Comment: There is a slight improvement after I changed ImageView's height to wrap_content and I can part of the Custom view now. But I want the Bitmap object (ie ButtonStart) to be on top of the ImageView, not under the ImageView. Something like drawing a button (Custom View) on top of a picture (ImageView). What should I do? @MagicMicky

Comment: @Wallyfull `android:orientation="vertical"` so it works the way it is working now. Use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks a lot. It works the way I want now. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" //it should be wrap_content otherwise it will take whole space
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/screenimage"
    >
    </ImageView>
    <com.lowbband.chimera.TitleView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleview"/>
```

And if the image is large and still fills the screen then put ScrollView outside LinearLayout